# VBA: For-Loop should not stop when encountering an error, it should jump to the next block

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I need to modify a for-loop, so that it skips to the next iteration when it does not find an object. Here is a snippet:

```
For j = 0 To i - 1

  Proj = Cells(3 + j, 2).Value

  ResClass = Cells(3 + j, 3).Value

    Set project = resq.Projects.Item(Proj)
    Set class = project.ReservingClasses(ResClass)

    Set CFP = class.Vectors("Cashflow DFM JM").Method
    Set CFPvol5 = class.Vectors("Cashflow DFM JM vol5").Method
    Set CFPTr = class.Vectors("Cashflow DFM JM Tr").Method

    orig = project.OriginCount 

For k = 1 To orig

            Cells(20 - 3, 4) = "DFM JM"
            Cells(20 - 3, 4).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(20 + k, col) = CFP.CashFlowPeriodLabel(k) - orig
            Cells(20 - 2, col) = Cells(3 + j, 1).Value
            Cells(20 - 2, col).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(20 - 1, col + 1) = CFP.CashFlowPeriodLabel(1)
            Cells(20 + k, col + 1) = Round(CFP.DiscountedCashflows(k, 1), 0)
            Cells(20 - 1, col + 2) = CFP.CashFlowPeriodLabel(2)
            Cells(20 + k, col + 2) = Round(CFP.DiscountedCashflows(k, 2), 0)

            Cells(59 - 3, 4) = "DFM Paid vol5"
            Cells(59 - 3, 4).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(59 + k, col) = CFPvol5.CashFlowPeriodLabel(k) - orig
            Cells(59 - 2, col) = Cells(3 + j, 1).Value
            Cells(59 - 2, col).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(59 - 1, col + 1) = CFPvol5.CashFlowPeriodLabel(1)
            Cells(59 + k, col + 1) = Round(CFPvol5.DiscountedCashflows(k, 1), 0)
            Cells(59 - 1, col + 2) = CFPvol5.CashFlowPeriodLabel(2)
            Cells(59 + k, col + 2) = Round(CFPvol5.DiscountedCashflows(k, 2), 0)

            Cells(98 - 3, 4) = "DFM JM Tr"
            Cells(98 - 3, 4).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(98 + k, col) = CFPTr.CashFlowPeriodLabel(k) - orig
            Cells(98 - 2, col) = Cells(3 + j, 1).Value
            Cells(98 - 2, col).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(98 - 1, col + 1) = CFPTr.CashFlowPeriodLabel(1)
            Cells(98 + k, col + 1) = Round(CFPTr.DiscountedCashflows(k, 1), 0)
            Cells(98 - 1, col + 2) = CFPTr.CashFlowPeriodLabel(2)
            Cells(98 + k, col + 2) = Round(CFPTr.DiscountedCashflows(k, 2), 0)

Next k
    col = col + 4


Next
```

If for a certain j in the first for-loop there is no CFPvol5 in the second for-loop, then the procedure stops with an error. I want the procedure to continue with the next block, in this case with CFPTr. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why are you using commands like `Cells(20 - 3, 4) = "DFM JM"` in a loop? They are independent of loop and iterator value. It just adds additional computation (it's enough to do it once).

Comment: Very good hint: I will take them out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shown 2 methods: Just a sample.

```
 on error resume next

         For i = 1 to x
        'do your stuff here

        next

        on error goto 0
```

or

```
on error goto nextLoop
for i = 1 to x

' do your stuff here

nextLoop:
next
```